# JAXB: How do I annotate classes so that they belong to different namespaces?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, urn

I want to have **JAXB-annotated** classes which would be
marshalled/unmarshalled to **different XML namespaces**.

What I need is something like:

```
<someRootElement xmlns="urn:my:ns1"
    xmlns:a="urn:my:ns2" xmlns:b="urn:my:ns3">

  <someElement/>
  <a:someElement/>
  <b:someElement/>

</someRootElement>
```

How can it be done?

Can it be done programatically?
(**without** the need for JAXB's **.xjb bindings file**?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@XmlRootElement(name="someRootElement", namespace = "urn:my:ns1")
class Test {
    @XmlElement(name="someElement", namespace="urn:my:ns1")
    String elem1 = "One";

    @XmlElement(name="someElement", namespace="urn:my:ns2")
    String elem2 = "Two";

    @XmlElement(name="someElement", namespace="urn:my:ns3")
    String elem3 = "Three";
}
```

This marshals into the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<someRootElement xmlns="urn:my:ns1" xmlns:ns2="urn:my:ns2" xmlns:ns3="urn:my:ns3">
    <someElement>One</someElement>
    <ns2:someElement>Two</ns2:someElement>
    <ns3:someElement>Three</ns3:someElement>
</someRootElement>
```

If you are using JAXB RI  and don't like the default `ns2` and `ns3` namespace prefixes, you need to provide your own [`NamespacePrefixMapper`](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/jaxb20-ea3/docs/vendorProperties.html).