# How make JAXB generate XML correctly?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jaxb2, xmlbeans

I'm trying consume a webservice that uses two namespaces in soap request, but it doesn't accept any prefix. I'm using cxf to generate the client and the data-binding. When using JAXB as default data-binding this is the message sent to the web service's server:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns:ns2="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"
                     xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <cUF>31</cUF>
            <versaoDados>2.00</versaoDados>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2"
                     xmlns:ns2="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
            <ns2:consStatServ versao="2.00">
                <ns2:tpAmb>2</ns2:tpAmb>
                <ns2:cUF>31</ns2:cUF>
                <ns2:xServ>STATUS</ns2:xServ>
            </ns2:consStatServ>
        </nfeDadosMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But this isn't the format that the server expects. Using XmlBean as default data-binding I can generate correctly the message (as the server expects):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <cUF>31</cUF>
            <versaoDados>2.00</versaoDados>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <consStatServ xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="2.00">
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <cUF>31</cUF>
                <xServ>STATUS</xServ>
            </consStatServ>
        </nfeDadosMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, I'm really affraid about using XmlBeans, as another important part of my software was developed using JAXB, I probably will need change this to XmlBeans. After I've saw that the last release of XmlBeans was in 2012 I'm not confident that XmlBeans will be supported in future.
Is there a way I can  generate the message correctly using JAXB??

**UPDATE**

This is the wsdl of the web service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
              xmlns:tns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2"
              xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
              targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
                  targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <s:element name="nfeDadosMsg">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="nfeStatusServicoNF2Result">
                <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any/>
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
            <s:element name="nfeCabecMsg" type="tns:nfeCabecMsg"/>
            <s:complexType name="nfeCabecMsg">
                <s:sequence>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cUF" type="s:string"/>
                    <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="versaoDados" type="s:string"/>
                </s:sequence>
                <s:anyAttribute/>
            </s:complexType>
        </s:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="nfeStatusServicoNF2Soap12In">
        <wsdl:part name="nfeDadosMsg" element="tns:nfeDadosMsg"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="nfeStatusServicoNF2Soap12Out">
        <wsdl:part name="nfeStatusServicoNF2Result" element="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2Result"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="nfeStatusServicoNF2nfeCabecMsg">
        <wsdl:part name="nfeCabecMsg" element="tns:nfeCabecMsg"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="NfeStatusServico2Soap12">
        <wsdl:operation name="nfeStatusServicoNF2">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2Soap12In"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2Soap12Out"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="NfeStatusServico2Soap12" type="tns:NfeStatusServico2Soap12">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="nfeStatusServicoNF2">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2/nfeStatusServicoNF2"
                              style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2nfeCabecMsg" part="nfeCabecMsg" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
                <soap12:header message="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2nfeCabecMsg" part="nfeCabecMsg" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="NfeStatusServico2">
        <wsdl:port name="NfeStatusServico2Soap12" binding="tns:NfeStatusServico2Soap12">
            <soap12:address location="https://nfe.sefazvirtual.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeStatusServico/NfeStatusServico2.asmx"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

these are the most relevant schemas that are used to create **consStatServ** tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="leiauteConsStatServ_v2.00.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="consStatServ" type="TConsStatServ">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Schema XML de validação do Pedido de Consulta do Status do Serviço</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="tiposBasico_v1.03.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="TConsStatServ">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo Pedido de Consulta do Status do Serviço</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tpAmb" type="TAmb">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Identificação do Ambiente:
                        1 - Produção
                        2 - Homologação
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="cUF" type="TCodUfIBGE">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Sigla da UF consultada</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="xServ">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Serviço Solicitado</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="TServ">
                        <xs:enumeration value="STATUS"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="versao" type="TVerConsStatServ" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="TRetConsStatServ">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo Resultado da Consulta do Status do Serviço</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="tpAmb" type="TAmb">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Identificação do Ambiente:
                        1 - Produção
                        2 - Homologação
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="verAplic" type="TVerAplic">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Versão do Aplicativo que processou a NF-e</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="cStat" type="TStat">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Código do status da mensagem enviada.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="xMotivo" type="TMotivo">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Descrição literal do status do serviço solicitado.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="cUF" type="TCodUfIBGE">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Código da UF responsável pelo serviço</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="dhRecbto" type="xs:dateTime">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>AAAA-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="tMed" type="TMed" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Tempo médio de resposta do serviço (em segundos) dos últimos 5 minutos
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="dhRetorno" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>AAAA-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSDeve ser preenchida com data e hora previstas para o retorno
                        dos serviços prestados.
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="xObs" type="TMotivo" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Campo observação utilizado para incluir informações ao contribuinte
                    </xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="versao" type="TVerConsStatServ" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TVerConsStatServ">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Tipo versão do leiuate da Consulta Status do Serviço 2.00</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
            <xs:pattern value="2\.00"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Could you post your JAXB source (xsd or Annotated Java Classes) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. As this is a 3rd party web service, the only choice I had was edit the classes generated by JAXB. The first thing I've done was remove the **namespace** attribute from **package-info.java** file. Then I did the same in **ObjectFactory** class, here I just changed the **QName** constructor from:

> QName(String namespaceURI, String localPart)

to

> QName(String localPart)

Unfortunately these modifications didn't removed the prefix, so I've implemented my own [CXF interceptor](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html):

```
public class NamespacePrefixInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public NamespacePrefixInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
        addBefore(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        if (isOutbound(message)) {
            OutputStream outputStream = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
            CachedOutputStream cachedOutputStream = new CachedOutputStream();
            message.setContent(OutputStream.class, cachedOutputStream);
            message.getInterceptorChain().doIntercept(message);
            try {
                cachedOutputStream.flush();
                CachedOutputStream messageStream = (CachedOutputStream) message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
                String currentEnvelopeMessage = IOUtils.toString(messageStream.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                currentEnvelopeMessage = currentEnvelopeMessage.replaceAll("ns2:", "");
                currentEnvelopeMessage = currentEnvelopeMessage.replaceAll(":ns2", "");
                messageStream.flush();
                messageStream.close();
                InputStream replaceInStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(currentEnvelopeMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                IOUtils.copy(replaceInStream, outputStream);
                replaceInStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                message.setContent(OutputStream.class, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isOutbound(Message message){
        return message == message.getExchange().getOutMessage()
            || message == message.getExchange().getOutFaultMessage();
    }
}
```

With this interceptor I could finally remove the namespaces. The last problem was the namespace **xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"** should appear in **consStatServ** element. As all unecessary namespaces was removed after the modifications in JAXB generated classes, the workaround I did was simply create a xmln attribute in ConsStatServ class:

```
public class ConsStatServ {
    .
    .
    .
    @XmlAttribute(name = "xmlns", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String xmlns = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe";
    public String getXmlns() {
        return xmlns;
    }
}
```

I know this solution is a huge kludge, but I couldn't find another option.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to play with http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html annotation on the elements of your generated classes. It has namespace parameter you'll be interested in. We had similar issue before and were able to make it work with those manual updates.

See also [JAXB: How do I annotate classes so that they belong to different namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870691/jaxb-how-do-i-annotate-classes-so-that-they-belong-to-different-namespaces)

Comment: The web service don't accept any namespace prefix in the soap message. If the message have at least one namespace prefix, the return is rejected.

Comment: @brevleq that seems like a pretty significant defect in the service you are calling. Have they provided a reason why well formed xml that is valid against the provided schema is being rejected? Once multiple schema namespaces are involved, preventing the use of prefixes will likely result in the applicable namespace being declared repeatedly instead of 1 time at a higher level. Think of this as always using fully qualified java class names instead of having one import statement at top of class (this is not a perfect analogy but is close).

Comment: @brevieq Try setting "namespace" parameter on XmlElement annotation specifically on each element in the XML which need a namespace: nfeDadosMsg and consStatServ in your case. Try setting namespace="" on XmlType annotation as well. I know this is not the best way to deal with it, bit it was the only way to make it work in our case.